# How can I add security questions?

Tags: 8

I need to add security questions while user creating his account in Drupal 8. I need to use those security questions to retrieve his password, when user forgets his password.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Well at this time you have 2 modules but only for Drupal 7:

[Security Questions](https://www.drupal.org/project/security_questions)

> Security Questions provides administrator configurable challenge
>   questions for use during the log in and password reset processes.
>   Think of it like most bank website logins.

[Password reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_reset)

> The password_reset module allows for passwords to be reset without
>   involving e-mail addresses through the use of security questions.

There is not a 8.x branch at this time, so your best option is study the code and migrate one of them.

Comment: Thanks. But i need for Drupal 8. Is there any alternate method anyone can suggest for the same functionality.

Comment: @Teja58 at this time you need to write your own module

Comment: Just port them?

Comment: @kevin yes this can be a way.